# Replacing multiple rows in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, combinations

I got a question I created a random array using numpy like this

```
n = 3

np.random.seed(1)
arr = np.random.randint(0,2, size = (n,n))
```

and by doing that I got the next array

```
arr = [[0 1 1]
       [1 0 1]
       [1 1 0]]
```

What I want is to keep a row fixed and the other change it by a rows of zeros and then save it in a list for example in this case I want three arrays like this:

```
[[0 1 1]        [[0 0 0]      [[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]         [1 0 1]       [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]        [0 0 0]]      [1 1 0]]
```

and when n = 4 do the same, and so on.

I know I can replace rows by doing this:

```
arr[i] = 0 #for any i = 0,1,2
```

And I tried doing this for my example

```
for i in range(n):
    if (i == i):
        arr[i] = 0
        print(a)
```

but that gave me this output...

```
[[0 0 0]        [[0 0 0]      [[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]         [0 0 0]       [0 0 0]
 [1 1 0]]        [1 1 0]]      [0 0 0]]
```

Is a better pythonic numpy way of performing this requirment.
Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it but something like this should work

```
for i in range(n):
   result = []
   for j in range(n):
      if i == j:
         result.append(arr[i])
      else:
         rowOfn0 = []
         for k in range(n):
            rowOfn0.append(0)             
         result.append(rowOfn0)
   print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
res = np.zeros(shape=(n,n,n))
for position, element in enumerate(arr): 
     res[position, position] = element
print(res)
```

Where res is an array with your n arrays

Comment: Yes it works! Kinda new and didn't know about enumerate, quick question, in this code what does it mean the 'pos' and 'el' in the for loop?

Comment: Sorry pos is the position, el the element, for example list(enumerate(["a","b"])) returns [(0, "a"), (1, "b")], note that enumerate is a generator

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, @Carlos Eduardo Corpus?

```
def create_arrs(n,seed=1,MIN=0,MAX=2):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    arr = np.random.randint(MIN,MAX,size=(n,n))
    list_arrs=[]
    for i in range(n):
        arrx = np.zeros((n,n))
        arrx[i] = arr[i]
        list_arrs.append(arrx)
    return list_arrs
```

Here is the output for `n=3`:
[image]

Comment: Not exactly, it change one row to 0, but I want all to change to zero except one row, but thank you!

Comment: ¡Hola, @CarlosEduardoCorpus! I've edited the post to address your concern. Hope this helps as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

One correction for @Daan Seuntjens answer (I didn't make a comment because I haven't reputation to it)

> ```
> for i in range(n):
>     result = []
>     for j in range(n):
>         if j == i:
>             result.append(arr[i])
>         else:
>             rowOfn0 = []
>             for k in range(n):
>                 rowOfn0.append(0)
>             result.append(rowOfn0)
>     print(np.array(result))
> ```

**print(np.array(result))**